# NWN2 multiplayer on original campaign

Tags: pc, mods, neverwinter-nights-2

Me and my friends have the Neverwinter Nights 2 game with expansions but haven't played it in a while. I was wondering if it is possible, and under what circumstances, to play the original published campaigns in a multiplayer environment.

- Is it possible via LAN or virtual LAN?
- Is the performance decent?
- Can we add custom mods like [Kaedrin's stuff](http://nwn2customcontent.wikidot.com/), extra classes etc? If so, I assume every connected member would need to have the same mods, right?
- How would you describe the amount of effort required to set this up? What about time required for customization, such as changing the round = 6s parameter?
  *Most of us are more than experienced with games & computers.*

Answer (score 8):

There isn't much to it really.
Go into the multiplayer menu.

(pro-tip, the master authorization server was taken down, so add the following two entries into your hosts file "/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts"

> 0.0.0.0 nw2master.bioware.com
>
> 0.0.0.0 nwn2.master.gamespy.com

and instead of waiting 2 minutes for the time out, it will time out instantly)

If you are hosting, New game (or load game for subsequent play throughs) just set up your server once, and it keeps the settings from then on.

To join, just use the direct connect button, and type in the IP directly.  No virtual LAN required.

Performance is fine, I've rarely noticed any lag issues.  Occasional rubberbanding, but it's pretty rare.

I've not personally done any modding, so I can't really speak to that part.

As far as the original campaigns go, they work pretty well multiplayer.  I recommend turning up the difficulty, or taking less companions though, it doesn't count PC's against the party limit, so you could take a large party through the game and all the companions as well.  In the Original Campaign, if you have one player as the party face, they will want to lead the party, because the scripted scenes tend to choose either the party leader or the closest player to do the discussions.  Only the person actually talking gets to use Diplomacy, Wisdom/Int conversation options, etc.  In Mask of the Betrayer and Storm of Zehir it seems to only be the party leader that does the talking in those situations, so you can put the tank out front.

Comment: It is probably better (saner and also quicker) to use 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 (unless you have something listening on the relevant ports on your local machine?...)

Comment: I haven't tried with 127, but the benefit of forcing it to an invalid address is that it fails instantly.  I think a valid ip address will cause it to retry and wait for the full 2 minutes, even if it's not getting any responses.

Comment: it s rather the opposite : 0.0.0.0 should try to broadcast (locally, as any routers reached that way should then block this "any ip" broadcast to reach further than your lan, if they are configured properly), so any ip in your lan (including your own machine) could answer and cause delays, if something listens at this port... 127.0.0.1 will prevent paquets to go to your lan (ethernet, wifi, whatever) side, they will only go to your loopback interface, a very fast local virtual interface to your very own machine. See http://serverfault.com/q/78058/146493 , + http://superuser.com/q/65701/174998